# Json to php, can't get the data i need

Tags: php, arrays, serialization, json

i need some help geting some data from JSON to php, i have tried a lot of options, but can't get the results i need, please can some one of you help.

The data can be fetched by a url.
Here is the data from the url: `a:5:{i:0;s:3:"135";i:1;s:3:"177";i:2;s:3:"178";i:3;s:3:"166";i:4;s:3:"165";}`

I need to get the numbers that are inside the "" , example 135, and  the numbers after i's, example i:0, i:1 etc

Here is the code i have tired:

```
$string = file_get_contents("http://www.myweb.com/url.php?url=1");
$json_a=json_decode($string,true);
echo  $json_a['a:5']['i'];
```

I cant get any result.

Comment: tip: json_last_error\()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a:5:{i:0;s:3:"135";i:1;s:3:"177";i:2;s:3:"178";i:3;s:3:"166";i:4;s:3:"165";}`

This looks like a serialized string by `serialize` function of PHP.

Try `unserialize`. Here: http://php.net/unserialize

Your data output;

```
Array
(
    [0] => 135
    [1] => 177
    [2] => 178
    [3] => 166
    [4] => 165
)
```